# VBA - Record Set from csv file

Tags: vba, excel, adodb, recordset

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Opening csv-File via ADO-connection - Column Limitation to 255 / or just use another file type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11185191/opening-csv-file-via-ado-connection-column-limitation-to-255-or-just-use-ano)

I have the following code to open a csv file as a record set

```
Set cN = New ADODB.Connection
Set RS = New ADODB.Recordset
cN.Open ("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
               "Data Source=C:\data;" & _
               "Extended Properties=""text; HDR=Yes; FMT=Delimited; IMEX=1;""")
RS.ActiveConnection = cN
RS.Source = "select * from myFile.csv"
```

The above code works for files which have less than 255 columns. However, if my CSV file has more than 255 columns, I get only the first 255 columns of data. Is there any alternate way of opening a CSV file into a ADODB recordset?

Comment: @Sean Cheshire - That link does not have a satisfactory answer

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with access databases. You can't have more than 255 fields per table:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/access-2007-specifications-HA010030739.aspx
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/access-2010-specifications-HA010341462.aspx

Depending on your data, could you possibly transpose it, or split it into multiple tables?

Comment: unfortunately, no. The code snippet is actually inside a function that has a return type of ADODB.RecordSet. That is why, I am looking for an answer that can allow me to return some kind of data structure that will contain all columns and rows

Comment: Does the data have to be on disk immediately? Could you return an array or collection instead, then write to disk later?

Comment: I guess not, given your response to Sean. There is no "fix". You will have to find a workaround similar to that proposed in my comment above, or in the link from Sean.

Comment: other databases (MySQL, PostGreSQL) have different column limits on their tables. You *may* be able to load your data into another type of database, then return a recordset for that database. I'm not actually sure whether ADO itself has a limit of 255 columns, you'd have to check that. You could also make your own object representing your data, with the required methods/properties from RecordSet.

Comment: I am going to go with returning an array instead. Is it possible to return the entire csv file or do I have to return it row by row? Also, if you could give me your solution as an answer instead of a comment, I will go ahead and accept it.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I really don't have time to do this right now. I've just been given a lot of work. All the information you should need is in the link Sean gave you.